# How to disable portlet sharing

Tags: liferay

I want to disable sharing of my portlets in liferay 6.1.0 CE so the "Sharing" button won't be visible.

In my portal-ext.properties i set the following property:
theme.portlet.sharing.default=false

But it don't work. I restarted the server and cleared browser cache.
Is there another way to disable this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration property `theme.portlet.sharing.default` set default value for checkbox "Allow users to add Web Content Display to any website" by sharing-tab.

However, I don't found in source code any possibility to deactivate the sharing about configuration. 
But you can create a Hook and override the jsp:

`portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\portlet_configuration\tabs1.jsp`

Here info how to override jsp: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/overriding-a-j-4